# py-cpuinfo module not working correctly when compiling using pyinstaller or Cx_freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

So basicly i am tring to compile a simple module (py-cpuinfo) with pyinstaller or Cx_freeze with the same issue. It compile correctly but when launching the process, it create a lot of it until my cpu is full.

```
#testcpu.py
from cpuinfo import get_cpu_info
print(get_cpu_info())
```

[image: My cpu usage after launching the program]

The weird thing about it is that it's perfecty working in developement mode (python code)
[image: When launching with python]
When compiling i am using this parameters : `pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console  "C:/Users/Mouad/Desktop/Payloads/cookies-grabber/testcpu.py"`

Does someone know how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I founded the answer: https://github.com/workhorsy/py-cpuinfo/issues/174#issuecomment-1210459512. You need to use freeze support function to compile it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).